# how to generate execution plan to see effect of new column before actually creating the new column on the table

Tags: oracle

how to extract execution plan for table with new column before actually adding new column to that table?

Is it possible at all? If yes, please let me know how.

Comment: please read explain plan

Answer (score 1):

A new column per se does not impact an execution plan. What *might* alter a plan is what you end up doing with that column, and what data you put into it.

For example, if I have a 10GB table with 10,000,000 rows and do:

```
alter table T add NEW_COL varchar2(1000);
```

that table is still exactly 10G in size. It will take just a long to scan, and the optimizer will most likely come up with identical execution plans for existing queries.

But lets say I now run

update T set NEW_COL = rpad('x',1000);

Now every row in my table is 1000 bytes larger.  (I'm putting aside issues such as chaining etc here), which means my table is now 20GB in size. That can have a dramatic impact on plans (even for queries that do not access the new column) because the table size is larger - so scans become less attractive etc.

Execution plans are driven are estimates of how much it will cost to execute a query in terms of CPU, storage access etc, not by the addition of new columns.

Hope this helps